# Sort an SQL query not a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a database containing a large amount of information that a user can query using PHP to communicate with the MySQL database. I also want to limit their results to be at most 300 results, which I have successfully done. However, I also want to sort the results by dataset name. Is there a way to sort the end query, not the original table? From what I've read online, the ORDER BY statement in a query sorts the whole table and then does the query (or something similar) Sorting the query would be more efficient, as you would only be sorting say 15 records instead of 1500000. If it helps at all, I print the results to the page using the following syntax:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: the order by sort the query, not the table

Comment: `ORDER BY` will sort your query results in ascending order by default, or descending order with `ORDER BY DESC`.

Comment: Attention, pitfall. In any "raw" table, on any database system, you never have a guarantee how that table is ordered in itself. Only if you order the table in the query, you will be absolutely sure what 300 rows you get. Don't worry about the performance of such basic operations. Still, if you with to order only a part of the table, make a nested subquery, and order its result rows.

Comment: ...or if you sort the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a sub table and only sort on that you could attempt something like:

```
Select * from ( QUERY limit 300) a order by COLUMN
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result set is limited, save it into a php array then use the php sorting functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
$all = array();
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $all[] = $res;
}
usort($all, function($a,$b) {
    return $a['field'] < $b['field'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure what you are sorting by has a decent index and the sort option should be very fast. The issue with sorting before/after a LIMIT is that if it were possible (which it is with a bit of GROUP BY logic), it would change the actual results you get as opposed to just the order they return in.